# Permanently changing the bluetooth class of my Lubuntu 17.04 netbook

Tags: usb, lubuntu, bluetooth, bluez

Edit: It appears that transmitting the class is not important, I'm able to stream sound anyways, bluez is handling it all by itself. My phone knows that it's a laptop and not an actual portable sound system but whatever. It works :)

I want to set up my netbook with a USB bluetooth dongle as a portable audio device.

I can manually change the class by running

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 class 0x20041c
```

But that setting does not survive when the bluetooth service is restarted, even after editing /etc/bluetooth/main.conf to

```
[General]
Class = 0x20041c
```

It always defaults to 0x00010c instead.

Some older instructions say to edit /var/lib/bluetooth//config but bluez 5.43 only has a settings file in that folder. I was able to permanently set the bluetooth alias in there. It does not allow changing the adapter class though.

Any ideas?

I'm running a fresh install of Lubuntu 17.04.

Edit: I found this http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-bluetooth/msg67306.html

But I have no idea what the hostname plugin is supposed to be and whether it's relevant to my case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually setting the class is not required to transmit sound. Bluez handles it by itself. Case closed.